# Scraping Premier League player photos from premierleague.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

For the past couple of days, I have been trying to scrape the player image source links from the "https://www.premierleague.com/players" page.

I understand that this webpage is a dynamic webpage with more players being loaded and shown as you scroll down.

I hope to be able to get an executable code in either R or Python which outputs the list of the players name and the image source links in a dataframe.

I have tried writing scripts in both Python and R but it has only been returning 10 results with most of the image source links being "player missing".

[image: Image Source Return]

Below is the script I wrote to get this result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import os

r = requests.get("https://www.premierleague.com/players")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
player_elements = soup.find_all("tr", class_ = "player")
print(player_elements)
for elements in player_elements:
    print(elements['src'])`
```

Any guidance or help on this problem is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please choose **one** language that the question is about.

Comment: Note that the [terms and conditions](https://www.premierleague.com/terms-and-conditions) of the site forbid you from creating a database of material downloaded from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All information provided is for educational purposes only. Please note that the [terms and conditions](https://www.premierleague.com/terms-and-conditions) of the site forbid you from creating a database of material downloaded from the site.

You don't need to fetch the entire HTML code using `requests` or use large tools like `Selenium` for this task, and you don't even need `BeautifulSoup`. In this situation, the good solution is to use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the requests being sent to the server and try to find the API endpoint that provides the names we see on the page.

In this case, it looks like the following:

[image]

You can see here there is a `page` parameter in request for pagination. Take it, take all payload params:

[image]

Take request headers also (it help you mimic the behavior of a web browser when making HTTP requests) and voila:

```
import requests

url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players'

params = {
    'pageSize': 10,
    'compSeasons': 578,
    'altIds': True,
    'page': 0,
    'type': 'player',
    'id': -1,
    'compSeasonId': 578
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.premierleague.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()

        players = data['content']
        for player in players:
            print(f"Player name: {player['name']['display']}")
            print(f"Photo URL: https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/40x40/{player['altIds']['opta']}.png")
    else:
        print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

That's should be enough. You can try to change `page` parameter (now it's 0, i.e. first)

If you still need to manually retrieve dynamically loaded data like infinite scroll, then you may need to use a browser emulator like Selenium.